# ASP.NET MVC JQuery Modal Dialog content looks empty

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dialog, modal-dialog

I am trying to use jQuery to show a modal dialog box on the page when the user clicks a button.  This is something I've never done before.  It looks like everything works fine, except that I can't see the content on the dialog and I can't figure out why.

This is the modal div within the view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="activeStatusModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="activeStatusModalLabel">
    <h3 id="jobstatusactionh3" style="color:black"></h3>
    <p id="jobstatusactiontext" style="color:black"></p>
</div>
```

And this is the jQuery in the scripts section pertaining to that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#activeStatusModal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Job Status',
        modal: true
    });
});

$("a.btn").click(function (event) {
    //Prevent navigation to the jobs page.
    event.stopPropagation();

    var toggle = $(this);
    var ids = toggle.attr("id").split("-");
    var cid = ids[1]; //Customer ID
    var job = ids[2]; //Job ID

    if (toggle.val() == "Mark Inactive") {
        $("#jobstatusactionh3").text("Job " + job + " is currently ACTIVE.");
        $("#jobstatusactiontext").text("You can mark it as inactive by clicking Confirm. Marking a job inactive helps us know that you're done. You can always reactivate it.");
    } else {
        $("#jobstatusactionh3").text("Job " + job + " is currently INACTIVE.");
        $("#jobstatusactiontext").text("You can reactivate it by clicking Confirm.");
    }

    $("#activeStatusModal").dialog({
        buttons:
        {
            'Confirm': function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Jobs/ToggleActive",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { cid: cid, job: job },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data, status, jqxhr) {

                    }
                });
                $(this).dialog('close');
                location.reload(true);
            },
            'Cancel': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    $("#activeStatusModal").dialog("open");
});
}  //end toggle active/inactive
```

When I run it locally and inspect the page, this is what I see (notice the text having been set accordingly):

[image: Modal1]

[image: Modal2]

[image: Modal3]

Why does it look empty?

Comment: Probably not related, but why are you initializing the dialog twice (with different options each time)?

Comment: Can you post the css?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, there are multiple buttons on the page that are supposed to launch this dialog - each is associated with a different "job" and I need to be able to display text / post for the specific job associated with the button the user hits.

Comment: Yes I know. but what you should have is global variable for `cid` and `job` (or a global object containing those properties, and set then in the `$("a.btn").click(function (event) {` function, and then just initialize the dialog once with all the options.

Comment: But I'm guessing your issue with the display is related to css. Use you browser tools to inspect the styles associated with the `<h3>` and `<p>` elements

Comment: OK, I made cid and job global, and it looks like I fixed the text not showing by removing "class = modal fade;" from the div.  Thank you!